# It is undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined

I am just practicing code and it says error: Uncaught ReferenceError: numberofCake is not defined the I need help to find what causes it to not be defined the code is

```js
let numberOfCake = 0;
  console.log('Let us eat cake!');
} else {
  console.log('No cake Left!');
}
```

Comment: where is you if condition ?

Comment: The code as displayed is not correct syntax, can you add the if condition please

Comment: btw it could be a simple spelling error between `numberOfCake` and `numberofCake` as it differs in your question vs code

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your post, I think maybe your formatting got a bit messed up when you copied your code. So I'm not sure if this is going to really answer your question, but here is an example:

```js
let numberOfCake = 0;

if (numberOfCake > 0) {
  console.log('Let us eat cake!');
} else {
 console.log('No cake Left!');
}
```

This code here should work. Based off what you posted, my guess is you just have a syntax error in your code. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp) is more info on how to properly structure if/else statements.

If it isn't an issue with if/else syntax, you may be running into a scope issue. For a deeper explanation of scope in javascript, check out [this article](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp).